# MYSQL: I want to update all rows in a table with values from another table where values from the first table are equal to the second

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress

I am trying to update a damaged WordPress terms relation (in tables wp_terms and wp_term_relationships).

Some tags were entered in Wordpress with their "term_id" number instead of their "name", so instead of creating a relation with the original correct tag, a new tag was created with this number as its name.

(For instance, if tag "toy" had term_id -> 2010, the new tag was named as "2010" with a new random term_id, lets say 30453).

[image]

In the above table, the correct relation for both objects (3456 & 4362) is with "toy" (with term_id 2010), but the error created a new term ("2010") with another term_id (30453).
We want both object_ids to be related with 2010 as below:

[image]

Trying to repair the relationships and relate the object_id to the correct term_id, I tried the following SQL query:

`UPDATE wp_term_relationships JOIN wp_terms SET wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = wp_terms.name WHERE wp_terms.name REGEXP '^[0-9]*$' AND wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id =  CAST(wp_terms.name as INTEGER);`

(I am CASTing the wp_terms.name as INTEGER to avoid type mismatch, though I don't know if it is necessary.)

This query runs without error BUT returns "0 lines affected" and updates no data.

Can anyone explain why and propose a working solution?

Comment: Post sample data and expected results to clarify what you want.

Comment: @forpas I added some sample data to clarify things!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a proper join with an ON clause, on the correct columns like this:

```
UPDATE wppp_term_relationships tr
JOIN wppp_terms t ON tr.term_taxonomy_id =  t.term_id
SET tr.term_taxonomy_id = t.name 
WHERE t.name REGEXP '^[0-9]*$';
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=03f091f8e49646cd5875fd3eca29c6b5).

Comment: I am trying this but mysql returns " #1062 - Duplicate entry '5574-9' for key 'PRIMARY'", but there's no entry with this value...

Comment: @LucasCave the query updates only the column `term_taxonomy_id`. Is it the primary key of the table `wppp_term_relationships`?

Comment: No, it isn't. The primary key on the term_relationships table is Object_id. There's no such value also as '5574-9'...

Comment: @LucasCave then check for triggers that may run because of the UPDATE.

Comment: Show triggers on the database returns nothing.

Comment: your answer is correct and I am going to accept it, I just remove the checkmark because I can't point my comment to you.

Comment: @LucasCave I can't say what `'5574-9'` is. You must check your data to see why it interferes with an update statement.

Comment: There was an index on this columns which created the problem. I dropped it and the query worked as it should.